# Callback Function does not work with for Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

Why doesn't the `callButtonTwo()` function work on all buttons? Only button1 reacts to it?

```js
document.querySelector("h1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Working!");
})

var totalButton = document.querySelectorAll(".testSecond").length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalButton; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".testSecond")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var buttonNow = this.innerHTML;
        callButtonOne(buttonNow);
        callButtonTwo(buttonNow);
    });
}

function callButtonOne() {
    alert("I got clicked!");
};

function callButtonTwo() {
    var changeRed = document.querySelector(".testSecond");
    changeRed.classList.add("red");
    setTimeout(function() {
        changeRed.classList.remove("red");
    }, 300);
};
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="testFirst">Hello World!</h1>
<button class="testSecond button1" type="button" name="button">button1</button>
<button class="testSecond button2" type="button" name="button">button2</button>
<button class="testSecond button3" type="button" name="button">button3</button>
<button class="testSecond button4" type="button" name="button">button4</button>
<button class="testSecond button5" type="button" name="button">button5</button>
```

Comment: Note: `querySelectorAll` has to search the DOM and build a new NodeList **every time** you call it. Keep the list you got the first time and then use that in the loop, rather than calling `querySelectorAll` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your `querySelector` in `callButtonTwo` just finds the first button because all of them have the same class `.testSecond`.

One possible solution is to add the reference of the button which should be colored red to the `callButtonTwo` function and use the reference to add the class name.

It would look like this:

```js
function callButtonTwo(button) {
  button.classList.add("red");
  setTimeout(function() {
    button.classList.remove("red");
  }, 300);
};
```

And you would call it like this: `callButtonTwo(this);`

Here's a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wq2ot8vh/3/) based on the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

While, inside your click handler you have `var buttonNow = this.innerHTML;` which operates on *that* button, when you call `callButtonTwo` you say `var changeRed = document.querySelector(".testSecond");` which operates on the **first** button (no matter which button you click).

You need to tell it which button you are dealing with (e.g. by passing `this` as an argument)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `callButtonTwo` you're querying `.testSecond` again which will always return the first element in the page with that class. If you want to handle each button differently you should pass the button element as a parameter to `callButtonTwo`, like so:

```js
var totalButton = document.querySelectorAll(".testSecond").length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalButton; i++) {
document.querySelectorAll(".testSecond")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
var buttonNow = this.innerHTML;
callButtonOne(buttonNow);
callButtonTwo(this); // 'this' in this case is the clicked button element
});
}

[...]

function callButtonTwo(button) {
button.classList.add("red");
setTimeout(function() {
button.classList.remove("red");
}, 300);
};
```

I would also consider to change the way you're iterating your elements in order to query the DOM less frequently:

```js
// 'querySelectorAll' returns an array which can be directly iterated using its method 'forEach'
document.querySelectorAll(".testSecond").forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var buttonNow = this.innerHTML;
    callButtonOne(buttonNow);
    callButtonTwo(this);
  });
});
```